# What is the purpose of the XML Serializer getting the type of an object?

Tags: c#

What is the purpose of the `XmlSerializer` getting the type of the object?

```
//Instantiate Person class to hold data from XML.
Person ThatPerson = new Person(); 
XmlSerializer Cereal = new XmlSerializer(ThatPerson.GetType());
```

Comment: being able to write/read instances of that type? I don´t understand your question. How do you expect the serializer to work if not based on the static type-definition?

Comment: The serialize method needs the the class type so it know the properties of the expectd xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The serializer is prepared in advance depending on the metadata of the type, i.e. so that it knows what to expect *in advance*. That's the entirety of the reason.

You *could* make a case for using `GetType()` when serializing, but you'd still need to specify the type type when deserializing, for it to know *what you want*. This choice just moves the serialize and deserialize logic to the same time/place.

Comment: Also, the constructor generates a temporary assembly to assist with the serialisation. This can be cached and used for serialising multiple objects - whereas if you only passed the type to the actual serialisation method, that work would have to be repeated for every serialised/deserialised object.

Comment: @BigDukeSix when serializing, yes the it could be inferred from the type of the object that you pass in; when deserializing, you'd still need to tell it what you want *in the absence of an object to ask*

Comment: @MatthewWatson that's an caching implementation detail that can be solved internally; in fact, the `Type`-based `XmlSerializer` already does this globally: it doesn't create an assembly *per serializer instance* - it does it *per unique root type* (caveat: the more subtle constructors *are* per-instance); the same approach could be used at the instance level

Answer (score 1):

This primarily makes sense for deserialization, because parsing an XML file would be quite ambiguous. It also makes sense for serialization, if you're trying to serialize a derived type using its base type representation.

If this bothers you, you can always use generics to get type inference, i.e.

```
public static class XmlHelper
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string fileName)
    {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            return (T)xs.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }

    public static void Serialize<T>(T instance, string fileName)
    {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            xs.Serialize(sw, instance);
        }
    }
}
```

which would allow you to save a few lines in the future:

```
var person = new Person(); 
XmlHelper.Serialize(person, "person.xml"); // type is inferred
```

or

```
var person = XmlHelper.Deserialize<Person>("person.xml");
```